# Bad performance with HD7870. What can I do to improve?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

I'm actually using Ubuntu 16.04 and I having bad performance with my ATI Radeon HD7870. This is a discrete Videocard but I can't even run without stuttering 3d-rendered page. I'm actually using the basic driver that comes with Ubuntu.

What can I do?

Comment: There is beta (?) support for the GCN 1 family of AMD chips (which includes your HD7870) in the amdgpu driver, which is noticeably better than the radeon driver (which Ubuntu uses by default for < GCN 3 chips). Unfortunately at this point in time, this requires you to compile the kernel yourself. If someone is willing to outline how to do this, feel free to expand this comment into a full answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try installing the drivers from the PPA of oibaf which are more up to date

for that you need to open a terminal and use the following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
```

after the ppa was added you only need to update and upgrade your system if you use the opensource drivers

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

you will be prompted to confirm the upgrades and after a restart you should use the latest drivers of the ppa

to remove the ppa and drivers following commands would be used

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

and

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
```

to remove the ppa

after that

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

to apply the changes

alternatively you can try leaner desktop's to get more performance like mate lxde or xfce