# Ubuntu 16.04 blue tint screenshot

Tags: screenshot

All my screenshot and photos are with a blue tint overlayed. I can't upload a screenshot because when I upload the screenshot revert back to normal. What can I do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've just find out what was my problem. I installed 1 week ago some unofficial graphic driver for my GPU. After purged them, my photos are normal as it was.

This was the discussion on  [How I installed the unofficial driver, also there is a guide on how to remove it.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/862432/bad-performance-with-hd7870-what-can-i-do-to-improve)